# CLC/dfp debugging message in the console on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed

Looks like someone forgot to remove the `console.log` on the following file:

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/clc/clc.min.js?v=5efc9f55fa38
```

This is what I got in the console:

```
[clc] Initializing CLC
[dfp] Found ids: Array(1)0: "dfp-tsb"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
[clc] loading clc
[clc] # of adzerk placements: 1
[clc] # of dfp slots: 0
[dfp] -> targeting - Registered: true
[dfp] -> targeting - Reputation: 10k
[dfp] -> targeting - so-tag: javascript,c_sharp,base64,iso-8859-1
[dfp] -> targeting - X-Site: askubuntu.com
[dfp] -> targeting - Persona: FrontEnd
[dfp] Defining slot for dfp-tsb: /248424177/stackoverflow.com/sb/question-pages, sizes: [[300,250],[300,600]]
[clc] Placing ads after 920ms
[clc] overrides: Object
[clc] pendingZones Object
[clc] Loading: https://clc.stackoverflow.com/markup.js?.....
[clc] placing response Object
[clc] pendingZones Object
[clc] adding 1 styles
[clc] pending zones: Object
[clc] loading in-house ad content into zone 4 <div id=​"hireme" class=​"tex2jax_ignore clc-cp-container">​…​</div>​
[clc] zone 8 not filled
[clc] zone 16 not filled
[clc] dispatching event on  #document
```

I guess it's not intended... or is it?

Comment: Now we know you are frontend persona ...

Comment: Yup, my fault. Will get that fixed right up.

Comment: @rene I was thinking about hiding it... but it would probably require me to delete the stackoverflow profile :P

Comment: I just checked: my persona is undefined, I'm a nobody here ...

Comment: rene who? renevate the build without logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that.

I was working on our minification pipeline, and there was a bug in one of the [babeljs](http://babeljs.io/) plugins that I was using to strip out those `console.log` calls.

It's been fixed, but it might take a bit for the cache on that .js file to expire.

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks :) can you say which plugin of babeljs did you use for that?

Comment: Sure, it was one that I wrote specifically to get our pipeline to work with `babel-minify`. Plugin is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-hoist-loose-functions). Fix is [here](https://github.com/rossipedia/babel-plugin-transform-hoist-loose-functions/commit/b6099cbbd65b4e83c698d41ece0289a975860908)